# Why do I get a redirect loop (302) when using path-auto patterns on taxonomy terms?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, redirection, path-aliases

I am using pathauto to set up my URL's at the moment and they are working fine for nodes.
However when I set up a rule for taxonomy terms using [term:name] as the pattern I end up with redirect loops.

Can anyone explain why this is and how to remedy.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Any altrations in `.htaccess` ? pls post pathauto screenshot ?

Comment: It seems to have been due to caching and the rebuilding of aliases table. Once I left it for a while and cleared caches it was working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have been due to caching and the rebuilding of the alias table.

Once I left it for a while and cleared caches it was working as expected.